# cascading drop down list not is displaying the saved value during edit

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, cascadingdropdown

I am using cascading dropdown list for my project. It is working fine for Create page and the values selected was saved in the database. But during the Edit mode, the saved value is not displayed in the dropdown.

EDIT VIEW

```
        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.CatID, "Category", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("CatID", ViewBag.CatID as SelectList, "--SELECT CATEGORY--", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.CatID, "*", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            @Html.LabelFor(model => model.NocID, "Nature of Occurrence", htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                @Html.DropDownList("NocID", new SelectList(string.Empty, "Value", "Text"), htmlAttributes: new { @class = "form-control dropdown1" })
                @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.NocID, "*", new { @class = "text-danger" })
            </div>
        </div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
<!--Cascading Dropdown for Category and Nature of Occurrence-->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
    //Category Dropdown Selectedchange event
    $("#CatID").change(function () {
        $("#NocID").empty();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '@Url.Action("GetNoCs")',
            dataType: 'json',
            data: { id: $("#CatID").val() },
            // Get Selected Category ID.
            success: function (nocs) {
                $("#NocID").append($('<option></option>').val('').text('--SELECT NATURE OF OCCURRENCE--'));
                $.each(nocs, function (i, noc) {
                    $("#NocID").append('<option value ="' + noc.Value + '">' + noc.Text + '</option>');
                });
            },
            error: function (ex) {
                alert('Failed to retrieve categories.' + ex);
            }
        });
        return false;
    })
});
```

CONTROLLER

```
// Json Call to get nature of occurrence
    public JsonResult GetNoCs(string id)
    {
        List<SelectListItem> nocs = new List<SelectListItem>();
        var nocList = this.Getnoc(new Guid(id));
        var nocData = nocList.Select(m => new SelectListItem()
        {
            Text = m.Title,
            Value = m.NocID.ToString(),
        });
        return Json(nocData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }


    // Get Nature of Occurrence from DB by CatID
    public IList<nature_of_occurrence_ref> Getnoc(Guid CatID)
    {
        return db.nature_of_occurrence_ref.Where(m => m.CatID == CatID).ToList();
    }
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated. 
Thank you. :)

Comment: There are multiple issues with your code. You cannot use the same name for the property your binding to and the `SelectList` (`CatID` in your case) and you need to populate both SelectList's in the controller based on the values your binding to. See both dupes.

Comment: Sorry I am new in using asp.net mvc for development and this is for my practice project. Can you please tell me the right approach for this? Thanks.

Comment: Read both the duplicates!

Comment: Already found a solution on this problem. Just took a long time posting an update here. I refactor my code and even the way I fetch the data from my database and come up into a much better and a clean solution. Thank for the help.